# SwiftUI TabView Page Styling

Tags: swift, swiftui, uitabbar, tabview

I am using a tab view with PageTabViewStyle to list out colors of a shirt, but the tab bar is barely visible with lighter color shirts and only shows the top half on darker. Is it possible to give the bar a background or change the dot color?

I've tried:

```
init() {
   UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .darkGray
}
```

But it didn't work.

Full Code:

```
struct PrintifyProductCell: View {
    var product: PrintifyProduct
    
    var images: [PrintifyImages] {
        product.images.filter { $0.position == "front" }
    }
    
    @State private var animating = true
    @State private var selected = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $selected) {
                ForEach(images.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: images[index].src)!) { image in
                        image
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(minWidth: 120, idealWidth: 160, maxWidth: 160, minHeight: 130, idealHeight: 180, maxHeight: 180, alignment: .center)
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                            .tag(index)
                    } placeholder: {
                        LoadingView(isAnimating: $animating)
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    }
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 120, idealWidth: 160, maxWidth: 160, minHeight: 130, idealHeight: 180, maxHeight: 180, alignment: .center)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .frame(minWidth: 120, idealWidth: 160, maxWidth: 160, minHeight: 130, idealHeight: 180, maxHeight: 180, alignment: .center)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .padding(.horizontal, 6)
            .padding(.top, 6)
            
            
            Text(product.title)
        }
        .background(Color(UIColor.uStadium.lightGray))
        .cornerRadius(8)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the code...